# Django: blog image not uploading properly

Tags: python, django

I'm sure i'm obviouly did something very stupid but, when I try to upload my profile picture on my blog website, even when I add one through admin page, the picture doesn't come up..

so here's what's happening,

blog pic:

[image: 1]

the picture right next to Kimmc6008, I should see my image, but somehow failed..

here's the code, I will upload more if needed.
models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class CategoryBlog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryBlog)
    featured = models.BooleanField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def blog(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post_list': post_list
    }
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)
```

and my html

```
<!-- post -->
            {% for post in post_list %}
          <div class="post col-xl-6">
            <div class="post-thumbnail"><a href="/post"><img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></a></div>
            <div class="post-details">
              <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="date meta-last">20 May | 2016</div>
                  {% for cat in post.categories.all %}
                <div class="category"><a href="#"></a>{{ cat }}</div>
                      {% endfor %}
              </div><a href="/post">
                <h3 class="h4">{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
              <p class="text-muted">{{ post.overview }}</p>
              <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center">
                  <a href="#" class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                      <div class="avatar"><img src="{{ post.author.profile_picture.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
                      <div class="title"><span>{{ post.author.user.username }}</span></div>
                  </a>
                <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>{{ post.timestamp|timesince }} ago</div>
                <div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{ post.comment_count }}</div>
              </footer>
            </div>
          </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Thank you for your help!!

**EDIT**
I noticed I was missing MEDIA_ROOT in my settings.py.
Would this be the reason why?

Comment: try <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}">

Comment: @noob Hi! thank you for your comment.
unfortunately, that didn't do it
Also, I noticed I was missing MEDIA_ROOT, would that be the reason why?

Comment: yes add in settings.py MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `upload_to` argument in your ImageField

```
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

And these are the basic settings you need to have in your django project for image/files handling

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [..]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
on the project/urls.py, I added what you told me to.
it somehow gave me bunch of errors, (red lines under "settings" and "static"
do I need to import things?

also, speaking of "upload_to='pictures'", is "picture" a fixed term? I've been using "images" for my code

Comment: @Jayden.devpro obviously you need to import these things. Check the answer.

Comment: @Jayden.devpro feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked